# Proper way to handle server-side protected routes in React?

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, protected

I'm new to this, go easy.
My understanding is that React code runs entirely on the client side, therefore having protected routes in react-router is just a UI convenience, they aren't actually protected at all, right?

so what is the accepted method for protecting routes in react apps? the only thing i can think of is to have multiple react apps, one is delivered when the user is not logged in, the other when they are logged in. is this correct? do i completely misunderstand how react works? thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

React is not really a paradigm shift in how apps are run, more so how they are organized. More cohesion instead of coupling, simple state machines; these props = this components initial state.

Everything you know about how web apps are built still applies. Can do server side rendering like this [react-starter-kit](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit) or no server side rendering like in [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app). React can be run on both server and client.

In the stated scenario, authentication would occur. Think the confusion is thinking you have the whole app by downloading the client. While this can be true, this is more often not the case. For something like say an admin panel, would configure webpack to move that into a separate bundle that is lazy loaded after your client bundle has authenticated as the admin role.

Think this really boils down to pure single page app architecture versus classic monolith, and has less to do with React. Hope that helps!

Comment: it does, thank you. i was referring to single page architecture, and i will research lazy loading and webpack bundling.